# How to determine the wordsize in Linux kernel programming?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, cpu-architecture

In userspace code, the macro `__WORDSIZE` is used, included in `<bits/wordsize.h>`. However, when I do Linux kernel programming, the `__WORDSIZE` seems not available.

If `<bits/wordsize.h>` is included, it will receive a compile error, saying:

```
error: bits/wordsize.h: No such file or directory
```

but if `<bits/wordsize.h>` is not included, it will receive another compile error, saying:

```
error: ‘__WORDSIZE’ undeclared.
```

It seems that kernel programming doesn't support the `<bits/wordsize.h>` header file. What should I do to determine the wordsize in Linux kernel programming?

P.S. my compiler version is `gcc (GCC) 4.4.6`.

Comment: A strategy for solving a problem like this could be to think about *why* you need to know.  Then think of existing kernel functionality with the same requirement, and go see how it is accomplished there.

Comment: Because I want to write different code target on x86 and x64, and `#if __WORDSIZE == 32` is a good way to do it.

Comment: What about if the target is neither?

Comment: I don't care, all the products in my company are **only** target on x86 and x64.

Comment: Then you should match those architectures, not a property they share with others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each supported architecture under Linux defines BITS_PER_LONG in
>   <asm/types.h> to the length of the C long type, which is the system
>   word size.

From http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch19lev1sec2

Answer (score -1):

Word Size in any architecture is equivalent to of size of long datatype.
So use
 `#define __WORDSIZE sizeof(long)`

You can alternatively use size of pointer too.